# JSON To JAVA object by Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm facing an issue while converting JSON string to Java object by using Jackson API ObjectMapper class.

Can somebody help me to convert below JSON to it's equivalent Java Object format.

Thanks in advance.

JSON String :

```
{

  "CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V": [

    {

      "CITY": "南京市",

      "ADDRESS1": "金箔路购物广场",

      "ADDRESS2": "江宁区东山镇金箔路999号(地下一层部分地上",

       },

    {

      "CITY": "南京市",

      "ADDRESS1": "金箔路购物广场",

      "ADDRESS2": "江宁区东山镇金箔路999号(地下一层部分地上",

    },

    {

      "CITY": "南京市",

      "ADDRESS1": "金箔路购物广场",

      "ADDRESS2": "江宁区东山镇金箔路999号(地下一层部分地上",

    }

  ]

}
```

Java Class :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import test.yiliservice.GetCUXOEORDERINFOV;
import test.yiliservice.ObjectFactory;
import test.yiliservice.YiliService;
import test.yiliservice.YiliServicePortType;

public class OrderInfoClient {

    public static void main(String ...a){


        try {
            YiliService yiliService=new YiliService();
            YiliServicePortType service= yiliService.getYiliServiceHttpPort();
            ObjectFactory factory=new ObjectFactory();
            GetCUXOEORDERINFOV request=factory.createGetCUXOEORDERINFOV();
            request.setIn0("password");
            request.setIn1("Y");
            request.setIn2("order_number = '60212191'");
            String response=service.getCUXOEORDERINFOV("password", "Y", "order_number = '60212191'");
            System.out.println("Response :"+response);
            //Convert JSON to a Map

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            MyPojo map = mapper.readValue(response, MyPojo.class);
            for (CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V b1: map.getCUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V()){
                System.out.println(b1.getORDER_NUMBER());
            }
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

## MyPojo.java :

```
   import java.util.List;

    public class MyPojo
    {
        private List<CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V> CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V;

        public List<CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V> getCUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V ()
        {
            return CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V;
        }

        public void setCUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V (List<CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V> CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V)
        {
            this.CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V = CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "ClassPojo [CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V = "+CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V+"]";
        }
    }
```

## Exception :-

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character
>   ('C' (code 67)): was expecting double-quote to start field name  at
>   [Source:
>   {CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V:[{"DEPT_NAME":"液奶事业部","SALES_AREA":"苏皖","OBU":"南京","HEADER_ID":19453912,"ORDER_NUMBER":60212191,"LINE_ID":142741593,"LINE_NUMBER":3,"ORDER_SOURCE_ID":0,"NAME":"联机","ORDER_TYPE_ID":1199,"ORDER_TYPE":"南京分标准销售订单","REQUEST_DATE":"2015-08-31
>   15:02:41.0","PRICING_DATE":"2015-08-31
>   15:02:30.0","ORDERED_DATE":"2015-08-31
>   15:02:56.0","LAST_UPDATE_DATE":"2015-08-31
>   15:34:25.0","PAYMENT_TERM_ID":1003,"TERMS":"60
>   Days","SALESREP_ID":101875802,"SALES_NAME":"谭艳兵","ORG_ID":179,"CUSTOMER_PRODUCTION_LINE":"null","CUSTOMER_ID":3595,"CUSTOMER_TYPE":"R","ORGANIZATION_ID":365,"SHIP_SITE_USE_ID":175067,"BILL_SITE_USE_ID":175065,"SHIPPING_METHOD_CODE":"汽运-汽运直营","CUSTOMER_CLASS_CODE":"null","CUSTOMER_NUMBER":"NJSG0001","CUSTOMER_NAME":"苏果超市有限公司","ORDER_CATEGORY_CODE":"ORDER","HEADER_FLOW_STATUS_CODE":"BOOKED","LIN_FLOW_STATUS_CODE":"AWAITING_SHIPPING","ITEM_NUM":"204104001900","ORDER_QUANTITY_UOM":"EA","UNIT_OF_MEASURE":"件","ORDERED_QUANTITY":30,"SCHEDULE_SHIP_DATE":"2015-08-31
>   23:59:00.0","INVENTORY_ITEM_ID":4696613,"PRICE_LIST_ID":11837,"PRICE_LIST":"南京分公司苏果超市价格","CURRENCY_CODE":"CNY","CONVERSION_RATE":null,"CONVERSION_TYPE_CODE":"Corporate","CONVERSION_RATE_DATE":"null","UNIT_SELLING_PRICE":32.8,"SUBINVENTORY_CODE":"C52","SUBINVENTORY_NAME":"C52:南京分仓","SHIPMENT_PRIORITY":"null","SHIPPING_INSTRUCTIONS":"YTNNJWJR150831006","SHIPMENT_PRIORITY_CODE":"null","FREIGHT_CARRIER_CODE":"远方物流","CUSTOMER_SITE_CODE":"175067","CUSTOMER_PROVINCE":"江苏省","CUSTOMER_CITY":"南京市","CITY":"南京市","ADDRESS1":"金箔路购物广场","ADDRESS2":"江宁区东山镇金箔路999号(地下一层部分地上","ADDRESS3":"null","ADDRESS4":"null","POSTAL_CODE":"210000","FIRST_NAME":"null","LAST_NAME":"樊雨花","COUNTRY_CODE":"null","PHONE_NUMBER":"null","SITE_COUNTRY_CODE":"86","SITE_PHONE_NUMBER":"52190235","TO_ORGANIZATION_ID":null,"ATTRIBUTE12":"null","CUSTOMER_CONTACT":"樊雨花
>   18951709189"},{"DEPT_NAME":"液奶事业部","SALES_AREA":"苏皖","OBU":"南京","HEADER_ID":19453912,"ORDER_NUMBER":60212191,"LINE_ID":142741574,"LINE_NUMBER":1,"ORDER_SOURCE_ID":0,"NAME":"联机","ORDER_TYPE_ID":1199,"ORDER_TYPE":"南京分标准销售订单","REQUEST_DATE":"2015-08-31
>   15:02:41.0","PRICING_DATE":"2015-08-31
>   15:02:30.0","ORDERED_DATE":"2015-08-31
>   15:02:47.0","LAST_UPDATE_DATE":"2015-08-31
>   15:34:25.0","PAYMENT_TERM_ID":1003,"TERMS":"60
>   Days","SALESREP_ID":101875802,"SALES_NAME":"谭艳兵","ORG_ID":179,"CUSTOMER_PRODUCTION_LINE":"null","CUSTOMER_ID":3595,"CUSTOMER_TYPE":"R","ORGANIZATION_ID":365,"SHIP_SITE_USE_ID":175067,"BILL_SITE_USE_ID":175065,"SHIPPING_METHOD_CODE":"汽运-汽运直营","CUSTOMER_CLASS_CODE":"null","CUSTOMER_NUMBER":"NJSG0001","CUSTOMER_NAME":"苏果超市有限公司","ORDER_CATEGORY_CODE":"ORDER","HEADER_FLOW_STATUS_CODE":"BOOKED","LIN_FLOW_STATUS_CODE":"AWAITING_SHIPPING","ITEM_NUM":"204104001400","ORDER_QUANTITY_UOM":"EA","UNIT_OF_MEASURE":"件","ORDERED_QUANTITY":16,"SCHEDULE_SHIP_DATE":"2015-08-31
>   23:59:00.0","INVENTORY_ITEM_ID":2148603,"PRICE_LIST_ID":11837,"PRICE_LIST":"南京分公司苏果超市价格","CURRENCY_CODE":"CNY","CONVERSION_RATE":null,"CONVERSION_TYPE_CODE":"Corporate","CONVERSION_RATE_DATE":"null","UNIT_SELLING_PRICE":42.08,"SUBINVENTORY_CODE":"C52","SUBINVENTORY_NAME":"C52:南京分仓","SHIPMENT_PRIORITY":"null","SHIPPING_INSTRUCTIONS":"YTNNJWJR150831006","SHIPMENT_PRIORITY_CODE":"null","FREIGHT_CARRIER_CODE":"远方物流","CUSTOMER_SITE_CODE":"175067","CUSTOMER_PROVINCE":"江苏省","CUSTOMER_CITY":"南京市","CITY":"南京市","ADDRESS1":"金箔路购物广场","ADDRESS2":"江宁区东山镇金箔路999号(地下一层部分地上","ADDRESS3":"null","ADDRESS4":"null","POSTAL_CODE":"210000","FIRST_NAME":"null","LAST_NAME":"樊雨花","COUNTRY_CODE":"null","PHONE_NUMBER":"null","SITE_COUNTRY_CODE":"86","SITE_PHONE_NUMBER":"52190235","TO_ORGANIZATION_ID":null,"ATTRIBUTE12":"null","CUSTOMER_CONTACT":"樊雨花
>   18951709189"},{"DEPT_NAME":"液奶事业部","SALES_AREA":"苏皖","OBU":"南京","HEADER_ID":19453912,"ORDER_NUMBER":60212191,"LINE_ID":142741585,"LINE_NUMBER":2,"ORDER_SOURCE_ID":0,"NAME":"联机","ORDER_TYPE_ID":1199,"ORDER_TYPE":"南京分标准销售订单","REQUEST_DATE":"2015-08-31
>   15:02:41.0","PRICING_DATE":"2015-08-31
>   15:02:30.0","ORDERED_DATE":"2015-08-31
>   15:02:50.0","LAST_UPDATE_DATE":"2015-08-31
>   15:34:26.0","PAYMENT_TERM_ID":1003,"TERMS":"60
>   Days","SALESREP_ID":101875802,"SALES_NAME":"谭艳兵","ORG_ID":179,"CUSTOMER_PRODUCTION_LINE":"null","CUSTOMER_ID":3595,"CUSTOMER_TYPE":"R","ORGANIZATION_ID":365,"SHIP_SITE_USE_ID":175067,"BILL_SITE_USE_ID":175065,"SHIPPING_METHOD_CODE":"汽运-汽运直营","CUSTOMER_CLASS_CODE":"null","CUSTOMER_NUMBER":"NJSG0001","CUSTOMER_NAME":"苏果超市有限公司","ORDER_CATEGORY_CODE":"ORDER","HEADER_FLOW_STATUS_CODE":"BOOKED","LIN_FLOW_STATUS_CODE":"AWAITING_SHIPPING","ITEM_NUM":"204006000802","ORDER_QUANTITY_UOM":"EA","UNIT_OF_MEASURE":"件","ORDERED_QUANTITY":4,"SCHEDULE_SHIP_DATE":"2015-08-31 23:59:00.0","INVENTORY_ITEM_ID":4526768,"PRICE_LIST_ID":11837,"PRICE_LIST":"南京分公司苏果超市价格","CURRENCY_CODE":"CNY","CONVERSION_RATE":null,"CONVERSION_TYPE_CODE":"Corporate","CONVERSION_RATE_DATE":"null","UNIT_SELLING_PRICE":48,"SUBINVENTORY_CODE":"C52","SUBINVENTORY_NAME":"C52:南京分仓","SHIPMENT_PRIORITY":"null","SHIPPING_INSTRUCTIONS":"YTNNJWJR150831006","SHIPMENT_PRIORITY_CODE":"null","FREIGHT_CARRIER_CODE":"远方物流","CUSTOMER_SITE_CODE":"175067","CUSTOMER_PROVINCE":"江苏省","CUSTOMER_CITY":"南京市","CITY":"南京市","ADDRESS1":"金箔路购物广场","ADDRESS2":"江宁区东山镇金箔路999号(地下一层部分地上","ADDRESS3":"null","ADDRESS4":"null","POSTAL_CODE":"210000","FIRST_NAME":"null","LAST_NAME":"樊雨花","COUNTRY_CODE":"null","PHONE_NUMBER":"null","SITE_COUNTRY_CODE":"86","SITE_PHONE_NUMBER":"52190235","TO_ORGANIZATION_ID":null,"ATTRIBUTE12":"null","CUSTOMER_CONTACT":"樊雨花
>   18951709189"}]}; line: 1, column: 3]  at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1486)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:518)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:447)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1340)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:618)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:136)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3560)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2576)
>     at OrderInfoClient.main(OrderInfoClient.java:32)

Comment: Please add your Java class that isn't working

Comment: See here http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I'm getting JSON response in java class it is coming with double quotes like below .

```
{ CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V:[ {"DEPT_NAME":"液奶事业部"  ....
```

and I replace this with below

```
response=response.replace("CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V", "\"CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V\"");
```

Now it looks like below

> {**"**CUX_OE_ORDER_INFO_V**"**:[{"DEPT_NAME":"液奶事业部",

After I added double quotes it is able to convert as List..